# Conversion of SQL Hierarchical data

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a sql data

```
ID Name ParentID
1 BillGates 1
2 Paul Allen 1
3 Progam manager 2
4 Some Programmer 3
```

....

how do i recurse this into `List<Employee>` where Employee is

```
public  class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is my answer what you're looking for?  If not, could you provide an example input/output?

Answer (score 1):

To recursively get all of the employees under an employee you could use the following function:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetDescendents<T>(T parent, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
    {
        yield return parent;

        foreach (var child in childSelector(parent))
        {
            foreach (var grandChild in GetDescendents(child, childSelector))
            {
                yield return grandChild;
            }
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
var allChildEmployees = GetDescendents(employee, e => e.Children);
```

Comment: I need to Create the List<Emloyees> not parse through it.

Comment: Where do you need to create them?  From what source? Have you got a more detailed example?

Comment: I need the List<Employee> created from the data from SQL ex a dataset or a flat list of objects .

Comment: I would suggest putting an example with inputs and outputs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a dictionary of `Employee`:

```
Dictionary<int, Employee> employees;

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> ChildrenIDs { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Children { get; set; }
}
```

At first, read your employees directly, reading in their parent `ID`s.

Once they're all read, iterate over and replace the IDs by the `Employee`s references.

```
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    foreach (var id in employee.ChildrenIDs)
    {
        employee.Children.Add(employees[id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a short example?

Comment: I have n levels deep like a tree structure.

Comment: `replace the IDs by the Employees references`. Are you sure,can you keep that structure in the `Dictionary`?

Comment: See my answer for a recursive example

Comment: Shouldn't matter. Read in all your info from the DB, reading in indices only. THEN use the indices to get the employee reference.

Comment: @Olivier This is really an iterative process. There's absolutely no need to get recursivity involved.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Greens the BD isn't recursive. The process shouldn't be. It's not because you employees reference employees that it has to be done recursively.